# Divide a city in n parts

Tags: php, dictionary, geometry

I have city example: London with center lon, lat and radius of city.

I want to divide city region into 20 or n different circles and want to get lon, lat and radius of each region.

Is there any algorithm available in php?

Thanks

Comment: Divide circle into circles? It doesn't make much sense to me, tbh. Something like this? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/15987/2/apollonian_2D.png

Comment: Are the new circles concentric ? And with the same centre as the city ? (So that it will look like http://www.latinorebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Target.png)

Comment: There is no algorithm built into PHP which will do this, however if you know the math it could be possible to write a script. Do the circles overlap or have gaps between them?

Comment: @Wireblue a bit of overlap is not a problem in my case

Comment: MightyPork yes this is exactly I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an existing database/service to turn your lon/lat values into existing region/city/district information including zip/post code or NW, SW etc.  Providers often provide good APIs and example code for this to make your life easier.

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoding.html

Comment: That would me my last solution.. :(